# vuejs imports as services

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, vue.js, vue-resource

I was following this tutorial: https://auth0.com/blog/build-an-app-with-vuejs/

There they have used `import auth from './services/auth'`.

This is used in all files wherever we need to use the `auth` service.
So shouldn't it create separate instances of `auth` (and hence variables/objects defined in it)?

I was wondering how does this convert `auth` into a service(i.e. a single instance common across all vue components)?

Is it because of the vue-resource plugin? (I could not find this information in vue-resource plugin's documentation [here](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/tree/develop/docs)).

Comment: I don't really understand your question.In `auth.js` they are exporting default object so you can acess every property/method in another place if you import this file,by writing `auth.propertyName` or call method `auth.method(args)`

Comment: I am talking about that INSTANCE of object being common across all imports. (i.e. each import instead of creating new instance, is actually using a common object) @BelminBedak

Comment: Yeah and that make sense in this situation - thanks to VueJS reactivity.I don't know why you think the multiple instance would do better job in this case.You have a one object that is reactive and all methods related to auth module stored there.

Comment: I think your confusion is in thinking that new instances of `auth` are created every time it's imported. Instead, modules are sort of like singletons - even if they are imported multiple times, only a single instance is created.

Comment: @Peter thanks! Would you recommend a good link to details of the module system in es2015 where I would be able to better understand it?

Comment: @rahulserver anytime! This has a good section on modules: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch3.md